# echo command with variable and string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have 3 variables I'm trying to insert into an echo command that contains the string, as well.

Here is what I have:

```
1= "test1"
2= "test2"
3= "test3"

FileName= "WEATHERMAP"_"$1"_"STATE"_"$2"_"CITY"_"$3" 

echo $FileName
```

I want it to `echo WEATHERMAP_test1_STATE_test2_CITY_test3` 
 Instead I get `WEATHERMAP__STATE__CITY_`

I know this has something to do with the `underscore`, unfortunately, I need the `underscore`.

The only examples I have seen are putting two variables together, or it started with a `variable` followed by a string.

Comment: `FileName="WEATHERMAP_${1}_STATE_${2}_CITY_${3}" `

Comment: Also, Variables can also contain digits but a name starting with a digit is not allowed:

source [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html)

Comment: There should be no spaces preceding and following the assignment operator. Values should be assigned this way `a="test"`

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ misses the obvious, but catches the other two errors which none of the answers so far have bothered to point out. In general, use a syntax checker before asking here about basic scripting problems.

Comment: (Reported a bug; https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/663)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't start variable names with a number.

```
$ a="test1"
$ b="test2"
$ c="test3"
$ FileName="WEATHERMAP_${a}_STATE_${b}_CITY_${c}"
$ echo "$FileName"
WEATHERMAP_test1_STATE_test2_CITY_test3
$
```

Comment: This is similar to what @anubhava commented, but in my lab the _ after the first variable makes everything after it one long variable.

Comment: @buzzin thats why you have to put each variable into curly brackets `${var}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using bash by default, in which case letters, numbers and underscores are allowed, but you can't start the variable name with a number. You can achieve by following code :-

```
a="test1"
b="test2"
c="test3"

FileName="WEATHERMAP"_"$a"_"STATE"_"$b"_"CITY"_"$c"
## Also, can assign as below :
## FileName="WEATHERMAP_${a}_STATE_${b}_CITY_${c}"

echo $FileName
```

Answer (score 0):

The numerical variables are reserved for shell internal purposes, $0 contains script filename, $1 - first script argument, like ./script.sh first-argument, $2 - second script argument, etc.